# Redefining a function with a lambda or calling the standard API (Math.Ceiling)

Tags: c#, casting, lambda

I want to compute the *ceiling* division of strictly positive integers. I have the choice between the following two implementations:

```
var ceil = new Func<int, int, int>((a, b) => a % b > 0 ? a / b + 1 : a / b);
var x = ceil(y, z); // y and z being int previously defined
```

and

```
var x = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)y / (double)z);
```

This second version (Math.Ceiling) seems to be just the same as the first (with a lambda) but with 3 conversions added. So I feel like using the first one. Am I missing something?

(edited to precise the fact that it's meant to only deal with strictly positive integers)

Comment: Why use a lambda here? Why not just use a normal function?

Comment: I doubt you'd see any significant performance degradation with the conversions.  Plus the `Math.Ceiling` is far more readable in terms of intent.  I wouldn't optimize until you know that this is a problematic piece of code.

Comment: @Konrad I'm not sure to understand your question. Are you saying the second version is the one or are you thinking of something else ?

Comment: I'd also stick with `Math.Ceiling`. You can safely remove the cast before `z` because it isn't required to get floating point arithmetic on the division

Comment: @kev I'd leave that cast in, because IMO it makes the code more self documenting. But that's just a matter of style.

Comment: The lambda expression allows me to reduce the scope of the function, and since I'm sure not to deal with negative nor zero, I can keep it very simple. (i'll comment my question to precise that limitation, sorry for misleading)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally, I'd avoid worrying about optimizing out the `int` -> `double` conversions, these will typically be the least of your worries in performance.  Yes, they can add up, but you'd need to be doing a lot in a tight loop or something similar.

I'd stick with the `Math.Ceiling()` since it's very obvious what you're trying to do and thus is easier to maintain.  If you find your code is slow, then optimize and attack the biggest trouble-spots first.

Timing these over **1 billion** iterations, it's 8,677 ms for lambda and 9,749 ms for `Math.Ceiling()`, but that's 0.0000087 ms vs 0.0000097 ms per call which is negligible.

Comment: Note that this might not be an apples-to-apples comparison. For example, the jitter can inline the call to Math.Ceiling but cannot inline the delegate invocation.

Comment: @EricLippert: Good point.  Just to clarify I wasn't showing the times to say, "hey, the lambda is faster!  Use it!" but to show that - roughly speaking - they are so close in performance that it's a very small optimization, if any, and loses some readability in the process.

Comment: A question purely for those with a curiousity about the internals, but @EricLippert do you know if it actually can inline a call to Math.Ceiling, which is `extern`?

Comment: @JonHanna: That's a good point, I forgot that it was extern'd. I don't know what the jitter does in that case. It would be interesting to find out.

Comment: @EricLippert Please do if you can. The satisfaction to the curious will be worth the extra over-thinking by micro-optimisiers :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to use a lambda instead of a method.

The second one is a bit ugly: You rely on floating point division to give an exact result when the dividend is an integral multiple of the divisor. While I can't think of a situation with 32 bit integers and double where this isn't the case, it still gives me a bad feeling. And if you later replace `Int32` with `Int64` it's suddenly no longer correct.

Just define a new normal method:

```
public static int IntDivisionCeiling(int dividend, int divisor)
{
  int quotient=dividend/divisor;
  if(dividend%divisor>0)
    return quotient;
  else
    return quotient+1;
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's a bug. If the quotient is negative then so is the remainder.

Comment: @Eric You're right. I misread that `>` as `==` and wasn't careful about the `then` vs. `else` part.